# How to check if email already exist for a user (emails[0].address) before try to use it to change the email of another user?

Tags: meteor

I have a method to change the user's address (every user has only one address, so it's `emails[0].address`).

In the method, `Accounts.addEmail(this.userId, newemail);` block finely the adding of an `emails[0].address` if another user has the same. I receive in client the `error.reason === 'Email already exists.'` Great.

But before calling `Accounts.addEmail(this.userId, newemail);`, I need to call `Accounts.removeEmail(this.userId, emailold);` who will remove the old address and leave `emails[0].address` free for `Accounts.addEmail(this.userId, newemail);` (wich, when there is no email address in an account, use nicely by default `emails[0].address`).

So how can I handle and stop `Accounts.removeEmail(this.userId, emailold);` if `newemail` is used as `emails[0].address` by any other user?

Below my method.

Thanks

```
// Change Email Address of the User
Meteor.methods({
    addNewEmail: function(emailold, newemail) {

        // this function is executed in strict mode
        'use strict';

        // Consistency var check
        check([emailold, newemail], [String]);

        // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
        // without waiting this one to complete.
        this.unblock();

        //Remove the old email address for the user (only one by default)
        Accounts.removeEmail(this.userId, emailold);
        //Add the new email address for the user: by default, setted to verified:false
        Accounts.addEmail(this.userId, newemail);
        // Send email verification to the new email address
        Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(this.userId, newemail);

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add the new email first, and if it succeeds (ie no one else is using it), remove the old one?

Comment: @Guig Cause each user must have only one address, so I need first to free `emails[0].address` to be able to write in it.

Comment: If you try to add the new address, either it succeeds and 1) you know the address is available and 2) you temporarly have two addresses for that user. You immediately remove the first one; or it fails and 1) you know the address is not available and 2) you still have just one address for that user

Comment: If I add the new address as a second address, I can't know that this address is used as primary by another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `users` collection directly, and handle any errors yourself. This is what I do:

```js
Meteor.methods({
  "users.changeEmail"(address) {
    check(address, String);

    const existingAddressCheck = Meteor.users.findOne({"emails.0.address": address});

    if(existingAddressCheck) {
      if(existingAddressCheck._id === Meteor.userId()) {
        throw new Meteor.Error("users.changeEmail.sameEmail", "That's already your registered email address!");
      } else {
        throw new Meteor.Error("users.changeEmail.existing", "An account with that address already exists");
      }
    }
    return Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {"emails.0": {address, verified: false}}});
  }
});
```

Comment: Great and elegant. I can't edit your answer for so few characters, but edit the two last lines : remove comma on the before last line and on the last add `);`  Thanks!